# importing controller in flutter causes could not resolve package error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

New to flutter, migrating existing flutter 2.7 code to 3, for this, I created new app from the scratch in flutter 3 and then copy pasted all the files under /lib folder from existing 2.7 code and then copied all dependencies from existing pubspec.yaml, then executed flutter  upgrade to upgrade all dependencies to latest version. Then when I ran flutter run command getting many such below errors. Kindly help

**Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'sixam_mart' in 'package:sixam_mart/controller/auth_controller.dart'**

I see the above error caused by below import statement in dart module

```
import 'package:sixam_mart/controller/auth_controller.dart';
```

I can see the auth_controller.dart exists in the same project, but not understanding why the code is importing the modules that are existing in same project? Please help me understand. I think the code must be looking to import the module from package:sixam_mart which is not the same project, but I can see the auth_controller.dart exist in same project. Is this code structure issue? or am I missing the concept. Please help! Thank you

**UPDATE**

The issue is with name property in pubspec.yaml which is now resolved after changing the name property to sixam_mart, thanks to @ShahedEmon this fix could have taken longer for me being new to Flutter

Comment: Maybe the new app you created you gave a different package name which is not `sixam_mart` thats why the importing issue.

Comment: @ShahedEmon, thanks for the pointer, I am new to flutter, when creating new project I just typed something like >flutter create test_app not sure if that referencing to test_app instead sixam_mart thats in existing 2.7 code

Comment: yes thats the case. because of  that you new app can't find `sixam_mart`

Comment: @ShahedEmon, I can also see in AndroidMainfest.xml that the package name is like com.myapp.storeapp but nowhere I could find in existing code sixam_mart other than in the import statements which are causing the errors, not sure where to look for sixam_mart in the existing code config

Comment: In the given code the package name does not appear to be sixam_mart but instead something like com.myapp.storeapp, so could that not be issue with package name ? am missing something ?

Comment: in pubspec.yaml check the `name` property. What is it?

Comment: @ShahedEmon, I changed the name property to sixam_mart, still getting the same error, even tried flutter clean and then flutter pub get but that did not fix the issue. Thank you

Comment: you have to change in pubspec and also everywhere `com.myapp.storeapp` to `com.sixam_mart.storeapp. you can try using [change_app_package_name](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name)

Comment: @ShahedEmon,Thank you so much, the issue is now resolved after changing the name property to sixam_mart, I think earlier the change did not get saved, now getting some other issues, that should be part of migration. Thank you for all your support

Comment: You're welcome.